# Using ENSwiftSideMenu for side menu

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `ENSwiftSideMenu` for displaying side menu.

The problem is I am not using navigation bar and instead using custom view. The navigation bar is hidden.

Now there is a method in the library which makes the navigation bar on top of side menu.

Like this : view.bringSubviewToFront(navBar)

Now I am using this method for my customView like this:

```
view.bringSubviewToFront`(customView)
```

But this does not work. I have the subclassed the `NavigationController` as suggested by the library but I am still not able to bring my `customview` header on top of side menu.

I added a method in the `NavigationController` class:

```
func bringHeaderToFront(headerView:UIView) -> Void {
    view.bringSubviewToFront(headerView)
}
```

But this does not work.

Here is the custom `NavigationController` code:

```
class CustomNavigationController: ENSideMenuNavigationController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


     let sideMenuController:SideMenuController = SingletonClass.sharedInstance.getViewControllerFromStoryboard("SideMenuController") as! SideMenuController

    sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuViewController: sideMenuController, menuPosition:.Left)

    //sideMenu?.delegate = self //optional
    sideMenu?.menuWidth = 220.0 // optional, default is 160
    sideMenu?.bouncingEnabled = false
    //sideMenu?.allowPanGesture = false
    // make navigation bar showing over side menu
    view.bringSubviewToFront(navigationBar)
}

func bringHeaderToFront(headerView:UIView) -> Void {
    view.bringSubviewToFront(headerView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - ENSideMenu Delegate
func sideMenuWillOpen() {
    print("sideMenuWillOpen")
}

func sideMenuWillClose() {
    print("sideMenuWillClose")
}

func sideMenuDidClose() {
    print("sideMenuDidClose")
}

func sideMenuDidOpen() {
    print("sideMenuDidOpen")
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Now how to bring my custom header to front / on top of side menu?